# React Native (android) - Download file

Tags: react-native

Need to download a pdf file when user clicks download button in my android app.

I have base64 string of my pdf, file name available, which I fetched from api.

Now how do I download this pdf ?

Read that we can use RN Fetch Blob, so I tried below code,

```
let pdfLocation = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + fileName + '.pdf';
console.log("writing file to - " + pdfLocation);
RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(pdfLocation, base64PDFString, 'base64').then((res: any) => {
  console.log("file written res -" + res);
})
```

From the console logs, I can see the file is written in the specified location, but if I navigate to that location in my android simulator, I can't see any files stored there.

[image]

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: to navigate ,do you use file// prefix before file path?

Comment: As of now, I am not navigating from the App. After creating the pdf, I manually open the simualtor's document directory, wherever it says it is storing, but can't find anything there!!

Comment: I found out that the location "/data/user/0/..." is a root directory which is not visible by default. So one need to root their phone to view this location ?   I would like to just download my file to the Downloads folder in my phone. Any suggestions ??